# What is the Big-O of this Code?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I thought the Big-O notation will be n^3, but the output does not even closely match my Big O:

```
 int bigO(int [] myArray, int x) {
     int count = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
         for (int j = i+1; j < x; j++)
             for (int k = j+1; k < x; k++) {
                System.out.println(myArray[i] + ", " + myArray[j] + ", " +
                   myArray[k]);
                count++;
             }
     return count;
 }
```

My Apologies, I should have "x" instead of "n"

Comment: `n` is not defined. Without it im not sure your question is answerable. Im guessiing its `myArray.length` but assumption is .....

Comment: @Jamiec You can get the running time in terms of `n` here, even if its definition isn't shown. What do you need the definition for?

Comment: @Dukeling - I don't. I thought someone who would be better at answering this *would*. Happy to admit i was wrong.

Comment: n is not defined, x is not used -> answer this question is impossible!!! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That's because your function does not perform exactly `n^3` operations.

Actually, it does `f(n) = (1/6)*n^3 - (1/2)*n^2 + (1/3)*n` operations (found it using [polynomial fitting](http://juanlopes.net/actually42/#0%200%201%204%2010%2020%2035%2056%2084%20120/false/true)).

But, by [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), `f(n)` is `O(n^3)`. The intuition behind this is:

- `(1/6)*n^3` is the dominant factor
- `(1/6)*n^3` grows within a constant factor of `n^3`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a static analysis for your code. Because the loops have all different iteration ranges, it's best if you start with the most inner loop and work your way from inner to outer loop.

- The most inner for loop has `n-j-1` iterations.
- So if you look at the 2 inner loops, you have `Sum (n-j-1)` iterations (for `j` in the interval `[i+1; n-1]`). So you have `(n-(i+1)-1) + (n-(i+2)-1) + ... + (n-(n-1)-1)` iterations, which equals to `(n-i-2) + (n-i-3) + ... + 1 + 0`, which is an arithmetic series and the result is: `(n-i-2)*(n-i-1)/2`.
- And now we loop over the outer loop and get `Sum (n-i-2)*(n-i-1)/2` iterations (for `i` in the interval `[0; n-1]`). This is equal to `1/2*Sum(i^2) + (-n+3/2)*Sum(i) + (n^2/2-3n/2+1)*Sum(1)`. These sums are easy to calculate and after a bit of rearranging you receive: `n^3/6 -n^2/2+n/3`, which is the same formula as the one of @JuanLopes.

Since your functions is `O(n^3)` (`n^3/6 -n^2/2+n/3 = O(n^3)`), your code doesn't have exactly `n^3` iterations. The dominant factor is `n^3/6`, and you will have about this many iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation is not a per-se feature of an algorithm! It describes how the output "grows" over time/space with respect to the size of the input. Define the "size" of your input and you can compute the Big-O complexity of it.

As soon as you **change** the definition of "size" of your input, you get totally different complexities.

Example:

Algorithm to apply a gaussian filter to a set of images of size X*Y

- With respect the no. of images the algorithm operates in linear time
- With respect the global no. of pixels to process the algorithm is quadratic

So the answer is: you didn't define your `N` :-)